# copy cell content from one column to another only when cell is empty

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy contents from column H to column C only if the cell in column H is empty.

If H is empty, i want to leave the text that is in column C.

Here is what I have, it copies the contents of H, but if H is empty, it also empties column C.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim BotRow As Long

Cells(Rows.Count, "H").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    BotRow = Selection.Row
    For lngRow = 1 To BotRow
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(lngRow, "H")) Then
            Cells(lngRow, "C") = Cells(lngRow, "H")
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is "I'm trying to copy contents from column H to column C only if the cell in column H is empty." meant to say "I'm trying to copy contents from column H to column C only if the cell in column H is **NOT** empty."

Comment: Or maybe you are "trying to copy contents from column H to column C only if the cell in column **C** is empty."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vbNullString` = `""` , so this will transfer data from H to C, only if there is data :

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim BotRow As Long

    BotRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    For lngRow = 1 To BotRow
        If Cells(lngRow, "H") <> vbNullString Then
            Cells(lngRow, "C") = Cells(lngRow, "H")
        Else
        End If
    Next lngRow
End Sub
```

Comment: @JonC : Glad I could help! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long
Sub Copy()

n = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To n
    If Cells(i, 8).Value <> vbNullString Then
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```